# How to handle different categories for OneHotEncoder in the pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

My problem is that I created a pipeline working fine, however when I apply the OneHotEncoder in the GridSearchCV, there is a mismatch of columns - Probably because of different classes in categorical features, right?

```
    ValueError: Found unknown categories ['Membran', 'Metal'] in column 15 during transform
```

The data is pretty famous and available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)

My first step was to create a class to select different types of columns:

```
class SelectType(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, dtype):
    self.dtype = dtype

def fit(self, X, y = None):
    return self

def transform(self, X):
    return X.select_dtypes(include = [self.dtype])
```

Then, I could go for the preprocess pipeline:

```
preprocessing_pipeline = make_pipeline(FeatureUnion(transformer_list = [
('Int', make_pipeline(
    SelectType('int64'), SimpleImputer(strategy='constant'),StandardScaler())),
('Float', make_pipeline(
    SelectType('float64'), SimpleImputer(strategy='constant'),StandardScaler())),
('Object', make_pipeline(
    SelectType('object'), SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value = 'No'), OneHotEncoder()))
]))
```

My goal here was to replace null numbers for 0, and null strings for 'No'.

My next step was to create the final pipeline with the classifier, then GridSearchCV it:

```
classifier_pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessing_pipeline,
                            Ridge())

param_grid = {"ridge__alpha": [0.01, 0.1, 1]}

X = train.iloc[:,:80]
y = train.iloc[:,81:]

classifier_model = GridSearchCV(classifier_pipeline, param_grid, cv=5)
classifier_model.fit(X, y)
```

And there it comes the error I said

Any guidance would be really appreciated!!!

Thanks,

Comment: After some research, I could sort it out according to [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12494) post.

It really looked like that problem it was said before. The point is that we have two choices: ignore the difference of columns and previously add them as 0 or label all the possible categories for the OneHotEncoder.

If you go for the first solution, just make it: handle_unknown="ignore" inside the OneHoteEncoder. Otherwise, use 'category' element.